# Question on how to manipulate terms in this expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, power-series, generating-functions

sorry for the vague title, i dont know how else to express what i mean with this question. But what i need to do is find out which terms on the RHS of the expression are constants. It is clear that it would be when $j=k$ but The sum $j$ goes from $0$ to $k-c$ when $k-c \geq c$ or $j$ goes from $0$ to $c$ if $k-c \leq c$. So it is hard for me to find the terms that would be absent of $\ln(x)$ terms.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k}{n \brack k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\ln(x)^{k} \frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{k!} \rho(n,k)\right)+ (\frac{1}{2})^n + 
\\
(-1)^n\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=c}^n \sum_j  \frac{(-1)^{c+k}(\ln(x))^{k-j} \phi(n,k)}{j!(c-j)!(k-c-j)!} $$
Note that $\phi(n,k)$ and $\rho(n,k)$ do not contain any $\ln(x)$ terms.

Comment: i don't understand the question. constants wrt what quantity? $x$?

Comment: @gt6989b No constants as in a term that has no powers of $\ln(x)$ such as $\frac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: Well, doesn't each of those sums depend on $x$? So the only constant seems to be $1/2^n$